# Login Form in using C# with MS SQL Database

Tags: c#

I'm making a login form in c# with sql database, when I login with the letter in capital, I still login which is not supposed to be wrong, because my username and password are not capitalized.

'''

```
        if (txtUsername.Text == "" || txtPassword.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter the required fields!", "Required", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-2BLPCL2;Initial Catalog=MEMINFOSYS;Integrated Security=True");
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblUser WHERE USERNAME=@USERNAME AND PASSWORD=@PASSWORD", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USERNAME", txtUsername.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PASSWORD", txtPassword.Text);
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);

                con.Open();
                int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Successfully Login", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    MainForm main = new MainForm();
                    main.Show();
                    this.Hide();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter the correct username and password", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
```

'''

Comment: If the SQL databse is a Microsoft SQL Server database, then the default collation is that it's case insensitive. Also, you should be storing hashed passwords in a secure way that doesn't allow you to ever get the plaintext version back. See [this Security SE question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords) for more info on that.

Comment: please add code to the question

Comment: And please tag the database technology you're using. SQL stands for "structured query language" and it's used to interact with Google's BigQuery, MySQL, PostgreSQL, Microsoft SQL Server, and many others.

Comment: I already add the code sir

Comment: In addition to what @Llama mentioned, a client app should not have access to the database table with passwords. Either it would use SQL Server user authentication, or an intermediate backend service should encapsulate the queries into some API.

Answer (score 1):

Let me say its a very risky way of authenticating the user , cause you have no encryption for the password . so better you do it . lets hash password with a salt you store in db and cmpare the password entered with the hashed one . the case concern that you have for the password is also solved this way .

```
    public HashModel Hash(string password, string salt = null)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            return null;

        byte[] saltBytes = null;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(salt))
            saltBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(salt);
        else
            saltBytes = RandomSaltBytes();
          
        var pepperBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Pepper);
        var fullSaltByte = saltBytes.Concat(pepperBytes).ToArray();

        var hashedPassword = HashMe(password,fullSaltByte); 

        var hashModel = new HashModel
        {
            HashedPassword = hashedPassword,
            SaltPart = Convert.ToBase64String(saltBytes)
        };

        return hashModel;
    }

    public bool Verify(string password, string hashedPassword, string salt)
    {
        var hashModel = Hash(password, salt);
        return hashedPassword == hashModel.HashedPassword;
    }
```